# No input file specified (al migrar de php74 a php8)

Tags: laravel, nginx, php8

Tengo un proyecto en producción con laravel, servidor nginx (cloud server) que estaba funcionando perfecto en php74, , hice todas las pruebas en el proyecto local y funciona perfecto al pasar a php8, pero al hacerlo en producción la página inicial me da el error:

> no input file specified

Copio acá mi .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}% [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Manejar el encabezado de autorización
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirigir las barras diagonales finales si no es una carpeta
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Manejar el controlador frontal
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

En php74 funcionaba perfecto, en php8 da el error, he leído que puede ser un problema con path_info pero no encuentro donde tocar.

En mi cloud tengo la carpeta public_html y dentro un link simbólico "public" que lleva a la carpeta public del proyecto laravel.

Si me puede orientar les agradezco.

ACTUALIZACION

Hice una modificación en las líneas 4 y 5 del .htaccess, acá lo publico de nuevo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}% [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
  </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Manejar el encabezado de autorización
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirigir las barras diagonales finales si no es una carpeta
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Manejar el controlador frontal
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Y ahora el error pasó a ser 403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Comment: ¿Dónde ves el error concretamente? ¿Revisaste el log de errores de PHP?

Comment: El error lo muestra al ingresar a la página, en el log no da error, hice una modificación en el .htaccess y el error pasó a ser un 403 forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. Ya lo publico en el post.

Comment: Prueba a renombrar tu archivo `.htacces` por otra cosa, por ejemplo `.htaccessBackup` e intenta acceder al sitio a ver qué pasa. No entiendo por qué motivo al migrar de PHP 7 a PHP 8 te metiste a modificar el `.htaccess`  ¿? ¿Puedes decirnos también que log de error verificaste? ¿Cómo se llaman los archivos y en qué carpetas se encuentran? Me refiero a los logs de error de PHP.

Comment: Acabo de renombrar .htaccess y se mantiene el error 403, en principio no modifiqué el .htaccess, lo hice luego porque en producción apareció el error de acceso. Los log a los que me refiero están en la carpeta del proyecto storage/logs.

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario. Te sugerí que renombraras tu `.htaccess` original y probaras, porque en ese caso se crearía **un nuevo `.htaccess` que en principio debería ser correcto**. Tu comentario me confunde. ¿Renombraste o no el `.htaccess`? ¿Tienes ahora un nuevo `.htaccess` que da error y tienes también el viejo (el que renombraste)? Es que no veo qué relación tenga `.htaccess` con cambiar de versión de PHP, sospecho que es otro tu problema. Revisa si en `public_html` hay un archivo de error, que puede llamarse `errorlog` o de otro modo según tu hosting.

Comment: Si usas nginx quizas deberias mirar su configuración y no la de .htaccess, pues no siempre nginx le hace caso al .htaccess (depende de la configuración de cada servidor). .htaccess es propio de apache, no de nginx, pero segun que hostings si pueden ser usados ambos, pero en otros no.

Comment: Si, renombre el .htaccess por 222.htaccess pero no se ha creado uno nuevo. Seguramente el problema está en otro lado pero me está costando encontrarlo.

Comment: Ok gracias.....

Comment: ¿Qué tienes en pantalla cuando intentas acceder al sitio con el `.htaccess` renombrado? Es raro que no cree uno nuevo...

Comment: La web es https://amparosrl.com.ar/ me aparece el forbidden

Comment: Si miras en tu carpeta `public_html` debe haber un nuevo archivo `.htaccess` que se habrá creando por defecto al intentar acceder al sitio. ¿Qué contiene ese nuevo archivo?

Comment: No crea uno nuevo, sigue estando sólo el renombrado.

Comment: Crea un nuevo `.htaccess` con esto solamente: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>`

Comment: Gracias che, al final lo pude solucionar modificando un enlace simbólico y el php.ini